# Filter data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three select menus: modality, bodyPart and equipmentModel and what I want to do is: when the user select a modality, it shows only the data of that modality, secondly appears the bodyParts available for that modality and finally the equipmentModels available for the bodyPart and modality selected. 
When the user selects this 3 menus the data is filtered in a chart (highchart).

My data format:

```
[
  {
   "x":1437001200000,
   "y":7,"bodyPart":null,
   "equipmentModel":"asfasf"
   }

]
```

I have this js code to do this (example for CT data):

```
var type1 = $("#s2 option:selected").text();
var type2 = $("#s3 option:selected").text();

$.each(chart.series[2].data, function(i, p) {
    if (p.bodyPart != type1 && p.equipmentModel != type2) {
        chart.series[2].data[i].remove();

    }
});
```

Although I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bodyPart' of undefined
```

And it only filters the data according to the middle menu.
I suspect that it is because when a point is removed the length of the serie changes and it starts to count from index 0.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `p.options.bodyPart`?

Comment: Its the same thing @HalvorStrand . When I select the bodyPart it filters but gives the error. I think its because of what I said "I suspect that it is because when a point is removed the length of the serie changes and it starts to count from index 0"

Comment: @wergeld do you have any ideia how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you try having your unfiltered data in one place and then you have a function which returns the filtered data? Then you use `series.setData()` to update the chart. I think it's always a good idea to use the separation of concerns. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData

Answer (score 5):

I think that you can make your chart in two ways. First of all you can add all your series to your chart and use series.hide() and series.show() for hiding and showing your filtered data. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show

```
$(function() {
  var mod, bodyP;
  $('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        showInLegend: false
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'CT ARM',
      mod: 'CT',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5],
      bodyPart: 'arm'
    }, {
      name: 'MRI BRAIN',
      mod: 'MRI',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7],
      bodyPart: 'brain'
    }, {
      name: 'MRI WRIST',
      mod: 'MRI',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5],
      bodyPart: 'wrist'
    }, {
      name: 'PET THYROID',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7],
      bodyPart: 'thyroid'
    }, {
      name: 'PET BRAIN',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [1.9, 6.2, 2.7],
      bodyPart: 'brain'
    }, {
      name: 'PET HEART',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [7.9, 1.2, 7],
      bodyPart: 'heart'
    }]
  }, function(chart) {
    $('.mod').change(function() {
      mod = this.value;
      if (mod) {
        Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {
          if (ob.userOptions.mod == mod && (bodyP ? ob.userOptions.bodyPart == bodyP : true)) {
            ob.show()
          } else {
            ob.hide()
          }
        });
      }
    });

    $('.body').change(function() {
      bodyP = this.value;
      if (bodyP) {
        Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {
          if (ob.userOptions.bodyPart == bodyP && (mod ? ob.userOptions.mod == mod : true)) {
            ob.show()
          } else {
            ob.hide()
          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

You can use for it your load callback function (when your chart will be loaded). Then you will not have any problems with changing index of series when remove one of your series.

As you can see I am checking values inside my forms after every change.

Here you can see an example how it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/2q1376Le/2/

If you want, you can as well remove and add series that will meet your requirements but I think it will be a little bit more complicated problem and it all depends on your number of data.

Here you can see this second method for making your chart:

```
$(function() {
  var mod, bodyP, exist,
    series = [{
      name: 'CT ARM',
      mod: 'CT',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5],
      bodyPart: 'arm'
    }, {
      name: 'MRI BRAIN',
      mod: 'MRI',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7],
      bodyPart: 'brain'
    }, {
      name: 'MRI WRIST',
      mod: 'MRI',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5],
      bodyPart: 'wrist'
    }, {
      name: 'PET THYROID',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7],
      bodyPart: 'thyroid'
    }, {
      name: 'PET BRAIN',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [1.9, 6.2, 2.7],
      bodyPart: 'brain'
    }, {
      name: 'PET HEART',
      mod: 'PET',
      data: [7.9, 1.2, 7],
      bodyPart: 'heart'
    }];
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: []
  }, function(chart) {
    $('.mod').change(function() {
      mod = this.value;
      if (mod) {
        for (var i = chart.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (!(chart.series[i].userOptions.mod == mod && (bodyP ? chart.series[i].userOptions.bodyPart == bodyP : true))) {
            chart.series[i].remove();
          }
        };
        Highcharts.each(series, function(p, i) {
          Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {
            if (ob.name == p.name) {
              exist = true;
            }
          })
          if (!exist && p.mod == mod && (bodyP ? p.bodyPart == bodyP : true)) {
            chart.addSeries(p);
          }
          exist = false;
        })
      }
    });


    $('.body').change(function() {
      bodyP = this.value;
      if (bodyP) {
        for (var i = chart.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (!(chart.series[i].userOptions.bodyPart == bodyP && (mod ? chart.series[i].userOptions.mod == mod : true))) {
            chart.series[i].remove();
          }
        };
        Highcharts.each(series, function(p, i) {
          Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {
            if (ob.name == p.name) {
              exist = true
            }
          });
          if (!exist && p.bodyPart == bodyP && (mod ? p.mod == mod : true)) {
            chart.addSeries(p);
          }
          exist = false;
        })
      }
    });

  });
});
```

As you can see I am not adding all my data to chart. I am adding only this data that is choosen inside forms. The problem is that I have to loop not only over my chart series (to check if it should be removed or not) but also over all not added series (to check if I should add it).

Here you can see an example how this code works:
http://jsfiddle.net/2q1376Le/4/

Kind regards

Update: If you want to have just three series and information inside your data, you can do it as well, changing my code a little bit.

The mod section will be almost the same, because mod is connected directly with series.

Your bodyPart parameter is specific for every point so you need to iterate over all your series and over all of this series points for checking if this parameter is correct:

```
$('.body').change(function() {
  bodyP = this.value, dataPoints;
  for (var i = chart.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    chart.series[i].remove();
  };
  Highcharts.each(series, function(p, i) {
    if (mod ? p.mod == mod : true) {
      dataPoints = [];
      Highcharts.each(p.data, function(ob, j) {
        if (ob.bodyPart == bodyP) {
          dataPoints.push(ob);
        }
      });
      if (mod ? p.mod == mod : true) {
        chart.addSeries({
          name: p.name,
          mod: p.mod,
          data: dataPoints
        })
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here you can see an example how it work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2q1376Le/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer @Grzegorz but want I have is different. Here you present separated series of the same mod and what I have is only three series (MG; CT; CR) but the points of this three series have different bodyparts. We cannot show or hide points, thats my problem

Comment: Thank you for specific information about your problem. I have changed my code to meet your requirements. You can see it in update section. Have a nice day.